# Custom Search Display Template in SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, display-template

In SharePoint 2013 Foundation, I have created a custom display template for search and have created a couple of custom managed properties. Due to an absence of the Publishing Feature, I only have the JS files to edit for display item templates (No HTML). While everything is working properly except for the custom Managed properties. They are not showing up the values. If I tried to show default values like Title, Path, DocId etc, work properly. The only problem is with custom managed properties.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you saying there is no HTML for the display template? how is that possible?

Comment: Aslan, Yes, I am saying there is no HTML for display template. And it is possible because it is Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794209.aspx

Go to Site settings --> Search Result Types. Notice that a Property Sync alert is displayed.

If you don't do this update, the newly added managed properties won't display in your search results.

Comment: Marko, I appreciate your help when nobody else could. But I'm afraid that this Property Sync alert doesn't show up for Foundation. I have worked so many times on custom Search Templates on SharePoint Server 2013 and have clicked on Update and that has helped.
No matter how many managed properties you create and how many times you update your display template (Js) for properties in Foundation, it never shows up the Property Sync alert.
Any ideas?

Comment: Look this tutorial from Bella Engen. Basicaly you need new result type and copy of original display template https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/09/06/how-to-create-a-new-result-type-in-sharepoint-server-2013/ (because you can't add new managed properties and sync in default result type)

Comment: This is exactly what I had tried to do as the very first thing but there simply isn't a content type to recognize the display template (associated HTML file) as we have in SharePoint Server 2013. So that copied HTML file becomes useless in the display templates gallery.
I have created a new result types and associated the custom display template (Js) to it but it doesn't show custom managed properties. It can show the default properties though. Like Title, DocId, URL, Path, etc. but not custom ones.

Comment: Try adding Hit-highlighted properties. => In the Web Part tool pane, choose to expand the Display Templates section, and then select Use a single template to display items. This will allow you to change the Hit-highlighted properties (JSON) field. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794240(v=office.16).aspx